# Open Message in New Outlook Window

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I'm using the "New Look" Outlook and when I select a message in the Inbox and hit Enter, nothing happens.   How do I open the message in a new window?

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard shortcut is Shift+Enter.

Double-clicking with the mouse also still works.

I am not aware at this time how to make Enter alone work as in classic Outlook.